# Normal math alphabet letters not appearing as italic

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math, mathspec

I am having a problem with the normal math fonts which is not appearing as italic.

```
abc&&\mathit{abc} \\% problem here: non-mathit (abc) not italic!!!!
```

[image]

I want to use `\RequirePackage[math-style=literal]{unicode-math}` to get all variants of the Greek characters (for example: `\upPhi`, `\Phi`, `\mathbf{\upPhi}`, `\mathbf{\Phi}`) appear right.

There is also a problem with `mathalfa` package in which some of the fonts are not appearing properly. My torture file (MWE) is given below.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[bb=px,cal=boondox,frak=boondox,scr=euler]{mathalfa}

    \RequirePackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \RequirePackage{longtable,xspace}
    \RequirePackage{mathspec}

    \RequirePackage[math-style=literal]{unicode-math}

    \def\alphabets{a\ {quick}\ {brown}\ {fox}\ {jumps}\ {over}\ {the}\ {lazy}\ {dog.}}
    \def\Alphabets{A\ {QUICK}\ {BROWN}\ {FOX}\ {JUMPS}\ {OVER}\ {THE}\ {LAZY}\ {DOG.}}
    \def\digits{0123456789}
    \def\Symbols{;:\#@\$!+\%-(\&)[*]\{\}.?|}
    \makeatletter
    \def\test[#1]{&%
     \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\xx\expandafter:\expandafter=\alphabets\do{%
       \ensuremath{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname{\xx}}\xspace%
     }&%
     \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\xx\expandafter:\expandafter=\Alphabets\do{%
       \ensuremath{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname{\xx}}\xspace%
     }&%
     \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\xx\expandafter:\expandafter=\digits\do{%
       \ensuremath{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname{\xx}}\xspace%
     }&%
     \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\xx\expandafter:\expandafter=\Symbols\do{%
       \ensuremath{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname{\xx}}\xspace%
     }
    }
    \makeatother
    \parindent=0pt
    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{center}
    \underline{Testing Greek characters.}\\
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Upright &\ensuremath{\upPhi}\\
    Italic &\ensuremath{\Phi}\\
    Bold Upright &\ensuremath{\mathbf{\upPhi}}\\
    Bold Italic & \ensuremath{\mathbf{\Phi}}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \begin{eqnarray*}\label{eqn1}
    \mbox{text}&&\text{text}\ \mathrm{text}\\% upright text
    abc&&\mathit{abc} \\% problem here: non-mathit not working!!!!
    (a+b)^2&=&a^2+2ab+b^2\\
    E&=&mc^2
    \end{eqnarray*}
    \begin{longtable}{lp{12pc}p{12pc}p{4pc}p{6pc}}
    mathbb \test[mathbb]\\
    mathbbb \test[mathbbb]\\
    mathcal \test[mathcal]\\
    mathbcal \test[mathbcal]\\
    mathfrak \test[mathfrak]\\
    mathbfrak \test[mathbfrak]\\
    mathscr \test[mathscr]\\
    mathbscr \test[mathbscr]\\
    mathrm \test[mathrm]\\
    mathit \test[mathit]\\
    mathbf \test[mathbf]\\
    mathbfit \test[mathbfit]\\
    mathsf \test[mathsf]\\
    mathsfit \test[mathsfit]\\
    mathbfsf \test[mathbfsf]\\
    mathtt \test[mathtt]\\
    %mathttit \test[mathttit]\\
    %mathbftt \test[mathbftt]
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

Could someone help me in sorting normal alphabets to italic without breaking the Greek characters?

Note: I am using `xelatex` on TL2015.

Comment: Please post a **minimal** example.

Comment: @HenriMenke, MWE is there.

Comment: Yes, an example is there but it's far from minimal.

Comment: The TeX file which I have posted here is a torture file, since I want to check if something breaks if a package is added or removed. It contains some Greek characters, mathfrak, mathscr, mathbb, mathcal, mathsf, mathtt etc. No extra content. Please let me know if that does not make sense.

Comment: Do you know about the `\symbf` and `\symup` and `\symit` (etc.) commands? You don't need `math-style=literal` to get both upright and italic greek unless you want to use unicode glyphs.

Comment: Hi @WillRobertson!  Do I need to add any other packages for `\symbf`, `\symup` and `\symit`? These shows undefined.

Comment: `mathspec` and `unicode-math` are not compatible; not to speak about `mathalfa`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not absolutely certain what you're asking, especially because your example is not compilable nor does it make a lot of sense.  `unicode-math` doesn't work with `mathspec` or `mathalfa`.  All those packages are mutually exclusive.

That said, I think what you want to achieve can already be done in the default settings of `unicode-math`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$abc, \mathit{abc}$

$\Phi, \symit{\Phi}, \symup{\Phi}, \symbf{\Phi}, \symbfit{\Phi}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we make the bold italic version of Greek?

Comment: Got it! `\symbfit{\Phi}` will do that. Please update the answer. I will accept that. The problem is that my TL version is 2015 and these features are only available after that.

Comment: @Jagath I've added `\symbfit{\Phi}`.